# How to identify an ES6 generator

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-harmony

Say I've got a generator function like this:

```
var g = function*() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
};

var gen = g();
```

How can I tell programmatically that `g` is a generator function, or that `gen` is an iterator?

This seems like one possibility:

```
g.constructor.name === 'GeneratorFunction'
```

Is there a better way?

**Update**: I ended up [taking an approach](https://github.com/dtao/lazy.js/blob/5e252f3779413743aa6eb15fe5f5f1062884ef3b/lazy.js#L5729-L5752) similar to [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21559723/105570), but using `eval` to first determine whether generators are supported on the target platform in the first place. Here is the implementation:

```
var GeneratorConstructor = (function() {
  try {
    var generator;
    return eval('generator = function*() { yield 1; };').constructor;

  } catch (e) {
    // If the above throws a SyntaxError, that means generators aren't
    // supported on the current platform, which means isGenerator should
    // always return false. So we'll return an anonymous function here, so
    // that instanceof checks will always return false.
    return function() {};
  }
}());

/**
 * Checks whether a function is an ES6 Harmony generator.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isGenerator(fn) {
  return fn instanceof GeneratorConstructor;
}
```

Comment: Or you could be more permissive with typeof gen.next === "function" && typeof gen.throw === "function"

Comment: This will only work if fn is actually created with GeneratorFunction right?  Is there a way to determine if an object in general was created from a generator? In firefox `gen['@@iterator']` seems to be defined but I can't figure it out for node.  I'm surprised iterators don't derive from Iterator so that `gen instanceof Iterator` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining your solution with other solutions, this avoids the need for the global `GeneratorFunction`:

```
g instanceof (function*() {}).constructor
```

Comment: Nice, this is the solution I came up with as well. Except I want to even handle the case where generators aren't supported on the current platform (in which case this solution raises a syntax error). So I actually `eval` a string that should evaluate to a generator function and get the constructor of *that*; and if it raises an error than I return false.

Comment: `Generator = (function*() {}).constructor` followed by `g instanceof Generator` is a little more clear imo.  Is there a way to tell if g() is an instance of a generator, i.e. `g() instanceof Iterator`?

Comment: @NickSotiros That isn't a Generator, it is a GeneratorFunction. When called it produces a Generator.

Answer (score 5):

The following image from the current ES6 draft is pretty informative for showing the relationships between generator functions and other objects:

[image: Figure 2 (Informative) -- Generator Objects Relationships]

So it looks like you should be able to use `g instanceof GeneratorFunction` if you have a global reference to `GeneratorFunction`, otherwise I think your current approach is just fine.

Here is how you can get a reference to `GeneratorFunction` and other related objects, borrowed from a [V8 unit test file](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/test/mjsunit/harmony/generators-runtime.js?r=17279):

```
function* g() { yield 1; }
var GeneratorFunctionPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(g);
var GeneratorFunction = GeneratorFunctionPrototype.constructor;
var GeneratorObjectPrototype = GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype;
```

Comment: Would there be a way to tell which generator a `GeneratorFunctionPrototype` came from? For example, to make a new iterator from the same generator that a given iterator came from ?

Answer (score 1):

To tell if something is a Generator:

```
const g = (function*() {yield 1;});
const GeneratorFunctionPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(g);

function isGenerator(thing) {
  return typeof thing === 'object' && thing.constructor === GeneratorFunctionPrototype;
}
```

In the original question this answers `isGenerator(gen)` true.
While `g` is a generator function. When you call the generator function you produce a generator.

But in most cases it's more important to ask if the thing is an *iterator*:

```
function isIterator(thing) {
  // If thing has a Symbol.iterator
  return typeof thing === 'object' && thing[Symbol.iterator];
}
```

Usage:

```
function *Pseq(list, repeats=1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
    for (let value of list) {
      if (isIterator(value)) {
        yield *value;
      } else {
        yield value;        
      }
    }    
  }
}

let q = Pseq([1, 2, 3, Pseq([10, 20, 30], 2), 4], 2);

for (let v of q) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

1
2
3
10
20
30
10
20
30
4
1
2
3
4

This is iterating over a sequence. If there is an iterator embedded in that sequence that then use yield delegation to iterate through that before continuing the sequence. Generators aren't the only thing that produce useful iterators that you can yield to.